# rand() and srand() function opengl visual cpp

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'me making a Pacman game in opengl and I need to generate 2 diferent numbers 0 or 1, that are responsable for the direction of my pacman deppending on the direction he's taking.

How can I generate a number with rand() function that generates 75% of randomness for one number and 25% of randomness for the other?

If I make:

```
n = rand() % 3;
```

It will get 2 different numbers. 
The problem is the percent of randomness I don't know how to make. I can make it with a cicle and a counter. But I was told I could do It directly in the rand() function. I search but I couldnt find nothing concrete on google.

Comment: `rand()` isn't very random, and has a large bias, just so you know.

Comment: Do you mean that you need one number to be selected 75% of the time, and the other number 25% of the time?

Comment: chris: Most `rand` implementations are plenty good enough for use in a game. Essentially none of them have a "large bias" in any useful sense. For some implementations, reducing the range with `%` does introduce some bias, but not enough that the player of a Pacman game would ever notice.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, true, but it's always good to have your eyes opened in case you'd choose it for something more important.

Comment: Here's a hint: think of a set of possible values that you can divide up so that you have 25% of them in one group and 75% in the other, then go from there.

Comment: Yes, I know it's very restricted and I can to use also srand(time(null)); But in this case I don't need very randomness. I need a restricted "AI" that chose 75% of the times one move and 25% other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always go with a equally distributed random range from `a` to `b` and check your condition on the value like this:

```
if((rand() % 100)>=75)
    // 25%
    ;
else
    // 75 %
    ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `<random>` library. The bernoulli_distribution will generate true with a given probability p, and false with probability 1-p.

```
#include <random>

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::generate_n(std::ostream_iterator<bool>(std::cout," "), 10,
                    std::bind(std::bernoulli_distribution(0.25), std::mt19937()));
}
```

prints:

```
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

rand() gives you a random number between 0 and  RAND_MAX (typical 32k)

So half the values will be between 0 and  RAND_MAX/2, 1/3 will be between 0 and  RAND_MAX/3 and 2/3 will be between  RAND_MAX/3 and  RAND_MAX.

Is that enough of a hint?